# Finding a rate of sphere area increase given its volume increase

Tags: derivatives

Volume of sphere, $V = \dfrac43 \pi r^3$
Surface area of sphere $S = 4 \pi r^2$
If we know, $\dfrac{dV}{dt} = R$

Let us consider both volume and area as composite functions, thus
$$\dfrac{dV}{dt} = \dfrac{dV}{dr} \times \dfrac{dr}{dt} = 4 \pi r^2 \times \dfrac{dr}{dt} = R$$
whence $\dfrac{dr}{dt} = \dfrac {R}{4 \pi r^2}$
since $\dfrac{dS}{dt} = 6 \pi r  \dfrac{dr}{dt}$, let the value of the $\dfrac{dr}{dt}$ into the second equation, to get the answer.
Is this approach logically correct? Thank you.

Comment: Please use [Mathjax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to make your question readable.

Comment: How did you get $6$ in S'? It should be $8$?

Answer (score 1):

Everything is fine until you did

> whence $\dfrac{dr}{dt} = \dfrac {R}{4 \pi r^2}$
> since $\dfrac{dS}{dt} = 6 \pi r  \dfrac{dr}{dt}$

$$\frac{dS}{dt}=8 \pi r  \frac{dr}{dt}$$
therefore
$$\frac{dS}{dt}=8 \pi r \frac {R}{4 \pi r^2}$$
and finally
$$\frac{dS}{dt}=\frac{2R}{r}$$

Comment: thank You so much. Thus, logically that approach (making the volume a composite functions, and finding thence dr/dt and putting it to the area formula) had a sound foundation, or?

Comment: by the way, how can I draw those nice formulae, in order not to bother Moderators with converting my writs to a proper form?

Comment: Press *Edit* for your post and start studying how they formatted your question